Is there a way to ensure an XML DateTime prop is serialized to wintertime if the date is during wintertime?
An XmlSerializer keeps serializing datetime's to summertime(+2) instead of wintertime) if the XmlModel has a property with the XmlAttrib with "DateType=Time" configuration.
The date specified was 07/03/2024 which should be wintertime(+1)
See code.
My question is if there is any way to specify wintertime in the XMLModel or for the datetime?
TimeZone: Brussels
Code:
string xmlString = "";
// simulate the mapping from front end to the request
var periodModel = new PeriodModel();
var time = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0);
var date = new DateTime(2024, 03, 07);
var dateWithTimezone = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date.Date.Add(time), DateTimeKind.Local);
periodModel.EndDate = date;
periodModel.EndTime = dateWithTimezone;

using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PeriodModel));
    serializer.Serialize(ms, periodModel);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();

    xmlString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}

Assert.NotNull(xmlString);
xmlString.Should().BeEquivalentTo("?");

XML Model:
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class PeriodModel
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "time")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

Result (part):
<EndTime xmlns="">19:00:00.0000000+02:00</EndTime>
Expected result:
19:00:00.0000000+01:00

The problem was the XmlSerializer will use the timezone we're in today, not the timezone of the date specified. The solution was to use a string instead of datetime in XML/WCF model and let the DateTime.ToString("") do it's thing.
The DateTime.ToString method will know which timezone to pick for a date during wintertime.

it does not matter, I had changed it to see if there's any difference, you can test it yourself if you're in the same timezone the outcomes should be the same

If you test with a time of day that would affect the date if wrongly shifted, do the date xml and time xml diverge? (That is time is shifted to +2 but date is still "before midnight"?) My suspicion would be that by specifying the "time" type, the date is not taken into account and the current mode of daylight-savings is applied?

^^ To mitigate, I'd recommend (if possible) to send the datetime as UTC and if needed also send the timezone/locattion along with it (in whatever form makes sense to you).

Why not use DateTimeOffset?

The problem is in the code and expectations. dateWithTimezone has no timezone. DateTime isn't used to represent time either. DateTime knows nothing about offsets or summer and winter time. At the very least use DateTimeOffset. XmlSerializer can directly serialize to a StringWriter too, there's no need for MemoryStream and the triple copies.

In airline ticket results the date and time are serialized as: 1) Date and local time along with the IANA Timezone name and 2) Full ISO8601, ie including the offset. The important part is local+tz name. Those don't change even if DST rules change. That's when you fly, no matter what. The DateTimeOffset parts are for convenience. Even when a UTC time is included, it's only an alternate for for Local+TZ Name

@Fildor the API receiving the request is expecting the timezone and is not using UTC

You mean it is expecting local time? Because in the XML shown, there is only offset, not timezone.

I think it has something to do with the fact that you're in summertime when you run this code. I think you can continue to test in this direction.

Currently trying to change the XmlAnnotation from date to string and use the DateTime.toString("custom format here") and this seems to work, I've to test further

The only safe way to do this is to save separately the local datetime and the timezone. While you can adjust for DST in the past, in the future the date on which DST starts/ends may change. There are times a government changes it with just a couple of weeks notice.
Storing UTC+offset is not the same and will fail when DST is changed.
